how to use postgres with dart server shelf using custom middleware
Hi i would like to use postgres with dart server-shelf but i dont know how to create custom middleware, but i do know where to pass this middleware namely in the pipeline with the function Pipeline().addMiddleware(postgresmiddlewarehere)
also i have an example of the log middleware
Middleware logRequests({void Function(String message, bool isError)? logger}) =>
    (innerHandler) {
      final theLogger = logger ?? _defaultLogger;

      return (request) {
        var startTime = DateTime.now();
        var watch = Stopwatch()..start();

        return Future.sync(() => innerHandler(request)).then((response) {
          var msg = _message(startTime, response.statusCode,
              request.requestedUri, request.method, watch.elapsed);

          theLogger(msg, false);

          return response;
        }, onError: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          if (error is HijackException) throw error;

          var msg = _errorMessage(startTime, request.requestedUri,
              request.method, watch.elapsed, error, stackTrace);

          theLogger(msg, true);

          // ignore: only_throw_errors
          throw error;
        });
      };
    };

How do i create middleware that allows me to have the postgres connection in every route, so that i could use raw sql querys
Future<Middleware> postgres() => {
   return await Connection.open(Endpoint(
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'postgres',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
  ));
};

